# PHPExcel returns Zero "0" in parsing for a formula in a xlsx file

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

I want to get the calculated value of Excel Functions via PHP .simply if the input is

```
 '=MAX(2,3,4,6)'
```

then the output  will be

```
 6
```

For this , I made an two php script with PHPExcel Library . One script will take that formula/function and will generate a xlsx file .

The second script will read that generated xlsx file and will give calculated value of given formula.

The process seems ok , but it could not generates value for a few functions . Such as for

```
"=INDEX({"zz","yy","xx"},2)"
```

and

```
"=INDEX({"zz","yy","xx"},MATCH(MAX({11,22,34}),{11,23,34}))"
```

My first script can generate xlsx file along with their formula's result .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VMQe.jpg)

but second script shows invalid result , it shows only 0.

Here is my first script        http://pastebin.com/vCErW5wf

and here is my second script

```
require_once 'a/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
 require_once 'a/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

 $inFile = 'index.xlsx';

 $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
 $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
 $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inFile);
 $value = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCell('C5')->getOldCalculatedValue();

echo $value;
```

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1):

Using `getOldCalculatedValue()` will return the last value calculated for a formula cell that was generated in **MS Excel** (and even then, it's possible to disable calculations in MS Excel, and this value won't then be set). A file generated by PHPExcel will not populate this value, so it will simply provide a default value of 0.

Generally speaking, you should always use `getCalculatedValue()` when trying to evaluate a formula value

Comment: I changed that to "getCalculatedValue()" .. but it gives me  same zero "0" and two warning .






Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel_prac\a\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\LookupRef.php on line 618

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel_prac\a\Classes\PHPExcel\Calculation\LookupRef.php on line 625

Comment: Then perhaps there's a bug with the INDEX function perhaps: `=MATCH(MAX({11,22,34}),{11,23,34})` returns a value of 3 in MS Excel.... but `{"zz","yy","xx"}` has entries 0, 1 and 2.... so the INDEX lookup is failing to find offset 3..... believe it or not, PHPExcel's calculation engine is not 100% perfection, but simply reverting to `getOldCalculatedValue()` is not even a a workround, let alone a solution

Comment: please let me know for any solution .

Comment: I'll do some debugging, and try and work something out

Comment: Here I get another solution , But I need to manually save my file. After saving , I get the correct output . I wonder if there is any way to do the saving process when creating the xlsx file  .

here is a video screen cast made for you . 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptGLNEqqf0g